# How much should an API's return data be simplified, in comparison to the data model?

Tags: xml, web-services, api, rest

I'm designing a somewhat RESTful API, and the data model is relatively complex and normalized. How simple should the API's returned data be?

Is it better practice to replace foreign keys or IDs with actual data from the related table, or is it better practice to return what's in the database and provide API methods to turn those IDs into usable content? Or... is it better practice to provide IDs in addition to usable data?

Here is an example of raw data from the database in the return data:

```
<books>
  <book-id>935</book-id>
  <book-author-id>64</book-author-id>
  <book-genre-id>5</book-genre-id>
</books>
```

Here's an example of returning just usable content:

```
<books>
  <book-name>Steve Jobs</book-name>
  <author-name>Walter Isaacson</author-name>
  <book-genre-name>biography</book-genre-name>
</books>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's really going to depend on how your data is going to be used. Generally, any time you need to drill down into detail, you'll want to provide a URL or ID that can be used.

For your example, Title isn't something you're likely to need to ever provide more detail on, so you're probably safe just including it directly. Genre also doesn't need more detail, but people might want to fetch all other books of that genre.

Author is almost certainly something you'd want more detail on, both biographical info and to find other books by them. Not only that, while your genre field isn't likely to contain duplicate names, your author certainly would.

Author should be a resource itself. So should genre. Both with links to them.

For real-world API design, you need to denormalize your resources a little bit. Joins are hell over http. Assuming that almost everyone who fetches a book will also want the author name, you should include it in the books resource. They might also want other information about the author, like his photo.

So for your example API, we've arrived at something like this...

```
<books>
  <title>Steve Jobs</book-name>
  <author href="http://example.com/author/64">
        <name>Walter Isaacson</name>
        <photo>http://images.example.com/author/64/photo</photo>
    </author>
  <genre href="http://example.com/genre/5">biography</genre>
</books>
```

Don't make too many assumptions for how developers will use your API. One of the great things about APIs is that developers start using it to create things you'd never have expected. Give them the raw tools and see what sort of awesome happens.

Comment: Assuming that there might often be multiple authors, would you opt to always have an "authors" element that supports multiple "author"? <books><authors><author>

Comment: Well, sure. Anything that you can do to make parsing of the data easier is always better. When trying to decide what to include in your api, opt for verbosity.

Answer (score 0):

I would say in general that your API should meet the requirements of the users of the API. In particular, "expose the datamodel" is not a good goal. You may in fact expose some parts of the data model, perhaps simplified, in order to meet the requirements. But a blanket answer of either do or do not expose foreign keys and such will depend entirely on the requirements.